# having trouble sourcing a file in Rmd

Tags: r

I am having trouble sourcing a file into my Rmd file.

I have sourced files before and can not figure out why this one won't work. I have my working directory set to the correct spot. I have a file called projects in that I have my "index.Rmd" file and then I have a folder "scripts" with includes "chart_1.R".

So my work flow would be projects -> scripts. In projects I have index.Rmd and in scripts I have chart_1.R

```
source("scripts/chart_1.R")
```

I should be able to access the chart_1 file but I am not able to.

It gives me the error "Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection"

Comment: Builds may happen in a different directory, and you have a _relative_ path to your main source directory.  You may need to turn this into an _absolute_ path.

Comment: Using an absolute path I get the error "Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : cannot open the connection"

Comment: There's not enough info to identify the issue.  Try putting `list.files('scripts/')` in your .Rmd to see if your file is where you think it is.  Otherwise check inside the chart_1.R file to see if it is trying to open another file itself

Comment: Yeah @dww that could definitely be it, that we're looking at the wrong problem altogether. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*2 solutions...*

**Preferred Solution**

Have you tried the `here` package? It's made just for things like this, and it might do the trick. Your solution would look like this:

- Install the package; it's on CRAN: `install.packages("here")`
- If you're not using R projects, define what "here" means by adding a blank file called `.here` to the `projects` folder.
- Use code like the following:

```r
source(here::here("scripts", "chart_1.R"))
```

Or,

```r
library(here)
source(here("scripts", "chart_1.R"))
```

Basically `here` works like `file.path`, in that it generates a filepath. But it always starts with your base directory, according to rules spelled out in the [docs](https://here.r-lib.org/reference/here.html).

Maybe this is overkill for your particular problem, but it's a wonderful package and worth trying out. It avoids using absolute paths, which render your code less reproducible if someone else were ever to download the `projects` folder to check out what you did.

**Workaround**

The `knitr` function `current_input` can get you the location of the `.Rmd` file, at least when used with the option `dir = TRUE`. And `basename` will get get you from a filepath to the location of the containing folder. So you could try this as a workaround:

```r
source(file.path(basename(knitr::current_input(dir = TRUE)), "scripts", "chart_1.R"))
```

Comment: I am still getting this error "Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection"

Comment: I added a workaround option. Try that one? I'm starting to suspect it's not an issue with _finding_ the file, though. What if instead you use either of the solutions I propose to get the absolute path (either `here` or `current_input`), but then instead of sourcing it right away you assign it to a variable (say, `script_name`), and then include statements like `print(script_name)` and `file.exists(script_name)` to check visually that you got it right and that `R` can find it.

Comment: Do remember to come back and let us know what works!

Comment: Thanks using the work around I got it to work

Comment: Wonderful! Happy Friday.